# Version compatibility issue Azure functions' Node and DirectlineJS es6 exports

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, botframework, azure-functions, direct-line-botframework

#### End Goal:

To create Azure Function running [Botframework-DirectlineJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) with binding to `Bot (Framework)` using DirectLine secret.

#### Issue:

The above mentioned Botframework-DirectlineJS uses ES6 export and Azure Functions support Node 6.5.0 max [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management). Hence the question how to import successfully the DirectlineJS in the index.js file of Azure function?

#### Error

````
```
2017-05-23T07:17:45.939 Exception while executing function: Functions.adapter. mscorlib: D:\home\site\wwwroot\adapter\importexportwrapper.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-hook\index.js:73:14)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\adapter\index.js:4:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32).
```
````

Currently the error was while trying to use [npm import-export](https://github.com/Macmee/import-export)

#### Files

- index.js

  ````
  require('import-export');
  require ('./importexportwrapper');
  let directLine = new DirectLine({
      secret: 'DirectlineSecretValue-here'
    }
    );```
  ````
- importexportwrapper.js

  `import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems like `import-export` or `node-hook` doesn't play well with functions / edgejs (the environment we use to run node).

A couple options to try:

- use babel to transpile es6 to es5 as a part of your deployment process.
- write your function in typescript (`index.ts`) which will do `import` transpilation automatically - though this may fail for module dependencies, I haven't tried it out

Answer (score 1):

You have three options: 1) Write your code using ES5, 2) setup a task runner (gulp/grunt/npm scripts) to convert your ES6+ code to ES5 using Babel, or 3) write your code in Typescript and compile it to ES5 via task runner/npm scripts.

The most straight-forward method would be: in your file `importexportwrapper.js` use `require` instead of `import`.

Example:

```
var directline = require('botframework-directlinejs');
```

[Babel + Gulp Option](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)

Install: `npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-babel`

Run:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/app.js") // your source files
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist")); // your compiled output directory
});
```

Read more about Azure Functions [Node.js versions here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#node-version-and-package-management)

Comment: its an out dated document esp the version part `6.5.0`