# Azure Functions - how to support ES6 imports/exports

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I really don't feel like rewriting all my code to require() etc and it is 2019...

Can I not use import/export as with ES6 way? Can you use babel with Azure functions CLI in VS Code? Im not sure how this would work together.

I'm using node 10 in my Functions 2.0

Comment: Its a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128985/version-compatibility-issue-azure-functions-node-and-directlinejs-es6-exports

Comment: Sure, but that was asked almost 2 years ago and surely things must have changed since then. Basically, that is saying it's not really possible. I'm just shocked that it's not as easy as just writing it.

Comment: Im trying this https://github.com/jawa-the-hutt/azure-functions-es6-boilerplate?files=1 but its pretty ol;d

Comment: refer to this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/improving-the-typescript-support-in-azure-functions/

Answer (score 1):

Like Digvijay, mentioned [Typescript support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/improving-the-typescript-support-in-azure-functions/) has recently been added which you could consider.

But if you'd prefer to still write them in JavaScript and use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile ES6 to ES5, this should be possible now too.

Typescript support for Functions is more of a tooling feature set which includes

- a @types package - [@azure/functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/functions)
- the [`scriptFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#using-scriptfile) property added to `function.json` which overrides the default `index.js` from being expected/loaded
- a couple of NPM scripts to streamline the developer experience

For using `babel`, you could start with the typescript template generated from the `func` CLI and make some replacements/modifications

- Use `babel` instead of `tsc` (Update the NPM scripts in `package.json` too)
- Use `babel.config.js` instead of `tsconfig.json`
- Update `.funcignore` accordingly

  - Change `tsconfig.json` -> `babel.config.js`
  - Remove `*.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Not supported yet, it is an open issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/104

As suggested in comments of that issue you can use ESM.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/104#issuecomment-611926094